# Android Studio: Gradle 'project_name' project refresh failed

Tags: android, gradle

I recently downloaded and installed the latest version of Android Studio Bundle 2.3.3. I get a Gradle 'project_name' project refresh failed error {Error:Could not download jsr305.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1): No cached version available for offline mode} every time I load up the IDE. I have a constant internet connection and I even have downloaded jsr305.jar and placed it in the gradle directory in the Android Studio program files, but the problem still persist. I have not yet started coding or developing the layout yet.[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faLie.png)

Comment: When does this happen? When you run application, sync gradle or when you start up Android Studio?

Comment: It shows up when I start up Android Studio.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If you haven't, let me know, I think I might know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> In your app's build.gradle file add the following:(use latest version)

```
android {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you update android studio it update every thing but forget to update Gradle path you can change your gradle path from menu File > OtherSetting  search for gradle and from that window opened for you change it.select new gradle from myComputer > C: >Users > Current User > .Gradle >wrapper > dist > folder you must select version gradle-3.3-all and here you go every thing ok rebuild your project

do not forget to update   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' in project gradle file to   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.3'